# Do background threads need to run as STA thread in MS Office add-ins if they doe not access the Office object model?

Tags: .net, multithreading, outlook, vsto, office-interop

I inherited some code for an VSTO Outlook add-in. There is a requirement that a background operation executes periodically. The operation basically makes some web service call and writes some files to disk. It doesn't access the Outlook object model at all. At the moment it is implemented as an STA thread which runs continuously that loops and sleeps to achieve the timing of when to do the work, the time interval is several minutes and doesn't need to be particularity accurate.

The claims that all processing on background threads has be done on STA threads or else Outlook crashes and pointed me to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2017). My interpretation of this article is that a STA thread is only required if I call into the Outlook COM model, otherwise I can't see how Outlook would even be aware that another thread is running.

It seems to me that I would be better off using a `System.Threading.Timer` that runs the work on thread pool thread rather blocking a dedicated thread on `Sleep`. I'd love to hear from anyone who has experience with doing this sort of thing in office add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

No, if it doesn't access Office objects/methods, it can be MTA.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't deal with Outlook objects from a secondary thread. When a background thread makes a call to the Office application, the call is automatically marshaled across the STA boundary. However, there is no guarantee that the Office application can handle the call at the time the background thread makes it. Latest Outlook versions may detect such cross-thread calls and throw exceptions at runtime.

Be aware that .NET includes four classes named `Timer`, each of which offers different functionality:

- [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8): fires an event at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8): executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8) (.NET Framework only): a Windows Forms component that fires an event at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment. This is a recommended way for running recurring work if you want to access Outlook objects in the event handler.
- [System.Web.UI.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer?view=netframework-4.8) (.NET Framework only): an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.